# Vector of different objects but same parent

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, polymorphism, object-slicing

I want to have a vector with objects "Rectangle" and "Triangle". I want to run a function from specific index of vector. Why it calls function from parent class? Code will explain my problem better than my description :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



class Shape {

   public:
    virtual void info() {std::cout << "IM BASE CLASS - SHAPE" <<std::endl;}
};
class Rectangle: public Shape {

   public:
      void info () {std::cout << "IM RECTANGLE :" <<std::endl;}
};

class Triangle: public Shape {
   public:

      void info () {std::cout << "IM TRIANGLE :" <<std::endl;}
};

int main() {

   Rectangle rec;
   Triangle  tri;

   std::vector<Shape> v;
   v.push_back(rec);
   v.push_back(tri);





 std::vector<Shape>::iterator it;
   for( it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it )
   {
     it->info();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you put objects derived from Shape into a `vector<Shape>` they are sliced to Shape objects so you call Shape methods

Comment: @doug How Can i call their mathods?

Comment: What you need is a polymorphic vector.

Comment: Also, `Shape` should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: You can't. If you want to put polymorphic objects in a vector you should use pointers to the base class. Alternately, you could use `std::variant` with variant holding all possible subclasses.

Comment: Make it a vector of pointers or references